# How can I write a histogram-like kernel filter for CoreImage?

Tags: ios, swift, histogram, core-image

In the docs for Kernel Routine Rules, it says 'A kernel routine computes an output pixel by using an inverse mapping back to the corresponding pixels of the input images. Although you can express most pixel computations this way—some more naturally than others—there are some image processing operations for which this is difficult, if not impossible. For example, computing a histogram is difficult to describe as an inverse mapping to the source image.'

However, apple obviously is doing it somehow because they do have a CIAreaHistogram Core Image Filter that does just that.

I can see one theoretical way to do it with the given limitations:

Lets say you wanted a 256 element red-channel histogram...

You have a 256x1 pixel output image. The kernel function gets called for each of those 256 pixels. The kernel function would have to read EVERY PIXEL IN THE ENTIRE IMAGE each time its called, checking if that pixel's red value matches that bucket and incrementing a counter. When its processed every pixel in the entire image for that output pixel, it divides by the total number of pixels and sets that output pixel value to that calculated value.  The problem is, assuming it actually works, this is horribly inefficient, since every input pixel is accessed 256 times, although every output pixel is written only once.

What would be optimal would be a way for the kernel to iterate over every INPUT pixel, and let us update any of the output pixels based on that value. Then the input pixels would each be read only once, and the output pixels would be read and written a total of (input width)x(input height) times altogether.

Does anyone know of any way to get this kind of filter working? Obviously there's a filter available from apple for doing a histogram, but I need it for doing a more limited form of histogram. (For example, a blue histogram limited to samples that have a red value in a given range.)

Answer (score 3):

The issue with this is that custom kernel code in Core Image works like a function which remaps pixel by pixel. You don't actually have a ton of information to go off of except for the pixel that you are currently computing. A custom core image filter sort of goes like this

```
for i in 1 ... image.width
    for j in 1 ... image.height
        New_Image[i][j] = CustomKernel(Current_Image[i][j])
    end
end
```

So actually, it's not really plausible to make your own histogram via custom kernels, because you literally do not have any control over the new image other than in that CustomKernel function that has been made. This is actually one of the reasons that `CIImageProcessor` was created for iOS10, you probably would have an easier time making a histogram via that function(and also producing other cool affects via image processing), and I suggest checking out the WWDC 2016 video on it ( Raw images and live images session).

IIRC, if you really want to make a histogram, it is still possible, but you will have to work with the UIImage version, and then convert the resulting image to an RBG image for which you can do the counting, and storing them in bins. I would recommend Simon Gladman's book on this, as he has a chapter devoted to histograms, but there is a lot more that goes into the core image default version because they have MUCH more control over the image than we do using the framework.